# Country wise access restriction in Django project

Tags: python, django

When an user open any link of Django project, before open this link, I want to apply country wise restriction. Admin has right to add country in Database table, if country is available in table, then url will open otherwise it will show a message, restricted country

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

You'll just have to find out the user's country (e.g. the [`django-geoip` package](https://django-geoip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and the free Maxmind database), then check the country determined with it against the list of countries in the database table/model, and raise an exception if it doesn't pass.

Comment: I have idea of above functionality in CodeIgniter. I have already applied in a PHP (CodeIgniter) project. In CodeIngiter I have created MyController and extends CI_Controller and write the function in MyController so before open any page it will restrict the user in My_Controller.
Like same is there any concept availabe in Django.

Comment: Write a middleware or a view decorator to easily share the code.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in two ways, one mapping the IP address to a country as @AKX has already pointed to or, mapping the latitude, longitude to a country. Any front end client Web/Mobile can use their native APIs to provide lat long for a user. This data can be used to query google maps API.
The api looks something like this and you'll have to register to get a key.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=<lat>,<long>&key=<key>

def check_for_whitelisted_country(lat, long)
    r = requests.get(api)
    if r.status_code == 200:
    data = json.loads(r.text)
    for item in data['results'][0]['address_components']:
        if 'country' in item['types']:
            country = item['long_name']
            # if country in database return True
```

Now to use this, consider this example class based view.

```
class DoSomething(views.APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        try:
            lat = request.GET['lat']
            long = request.GET['long']
            if check_whitelisted_country(lat, long):
               # permit the action
            else:
                return Response({"Failure": "Invalid client."}, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to know, in Django where I will write code for restrict the user. 
For example: In my Django application more than 50 urls are there. So it is not possible to write the codition in all function. I want to create a common function and apply in a single place this function should apply for all url.

Comment: @tarique I've updated my answer to demonstrate your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Middlewares in Django ( see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/middleware/) ).

Write your custom middleware having `request` as parameter. On each `request`, we get IP address in `remote_addr`. Take this IP address and find his country/region (you can use 3rd party APIs for this). [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35123097/6546277)
Check the user's region according to your restriction regions. If it's restricted, send error message in response.